# Vue.js: setting html <option> tag to default via "selected" doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, v-model, select-options

I want to set one of the available `<option>` tags to default. On the `<select>` tag I am using `v-model` and I know that the `vue.js` documentation states the following in regard to this:

> `v-model` will ignore the ... `selected` attributes found on any form
>   elements. It will always treat the Vue instance data as the source of
>   truth. You should declare the initial value on the JavaScript side,
>   inside the data option of your component.

So I am using the `selected` attribute with v-bind and passing either directly `true` to it or through a variable in the data option. Unfortunately it doesn't work. Here is an [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/saitam/9wcjza78/26/).

And here is the example code:

HTML

```
<div id="app">
  <select v-model="selectedData" @change="doSomething">
    <option :selected="true" value="">
      Please select account
    </option>
    <option 
      v-for="data in myData"
      :key="data.id"
      :value="data.val"
    >
      {{ data.val }} 
    </option>
  </select>
{{ selectedData }}
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    selected: true,
    selectedData: null,
    myData: [
      { id: 1, val: "abc" },
      { id: 2, val: "def" },
      { id: 3, val: "ghi" },
      { id: 4, val: "jkl" },
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    doSomething: function(){
        console.log('hello')
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<select>` tag's model is what is actually driving the chosen item in the drop down.

```js
<select v-model="selectedData" @change="doSomething">
```

Change your "default" option to the following

```js
    <option value="-1">
      Please select account
    </option>
```

and in your data object, instead of having `null` assigned to your selected value on initialization, set it to -1

```js
data: {
    selectedData: -1,
    myData: [
      { id: 1, val: "abc" },
      { id: 2, val: "def" },
      { id: 3, val: "ghi" },
      { id: 4, val: "jkl" },
    ]
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to set the initial value of the property bound with `v-model`, so `selectedData: ''` (instead of `null`). I'm not sure if I'm missing something else, but this is how I always do it.